# Sharepoint 2010 Show SPList on webpart from a remote SPSite

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts, splist, spsite

Im new to sharepoint and im trying to get a SPList from another SPSite i have on same farm, that itself is not a problem.

But i want to do something like this: http://prazjain.wordpress.com/2009/11/13/programmatically-add-splist-as-webpart-on-spweb-using-listviewwebpart/

problem is, it doesnt seem to work when the list is not on my current SPSite... 
Is there an alternative besides ListViewWebPart to show the SPlistItems from a different SPSite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross site-collection list display is not supported OOTB by SharePoint. There are workarounds with SharePoint Designer, web services, iframes, etc. But these are all hacks in my opinion.

I suggest to write a custom web part and display the data in a [SPGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx).